# OS X 10.7 Animation Did stop selector

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I am trying to figure out how to set a call back for when my nsview animator stops. Anyone know how to do this.

```
NSRect frame = blob.frame;
frame.origin.x = animationStopX;
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:timeToDisappear];
[[blob animator] setFrame:frame];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Comment: You really shouldn't ask the same question twice -- have a little patience. I posted an answer in your later post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set delegate for frameOrigin animation.

```
CAAnimation *moveAnimation = [[blob animationForKey:@"frameOrigin"] copy];
moveAnimation.delegate = self;
[blob setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:moveAnimation forKey:@"frameOrigin"]];
[moveAnimation release];
```

And override end animation delegate method

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
```

Answer (score 2):

On 10.8, `NSAnimationContext` has [`completionHandler`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimationContext_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) property which you can use with a block.

Comment: Although the completionHandler does not tell you wether the animation was successfully run through or called due to a cancellation. At times it's important to know how it ended.